# How to build gstreamer for Android on Windows?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to use gtreamer on Android Studio using [this](https://github.com/jaroslavas/Gstreamer-Android-example) example. My OS is Windows so I need to make some changes to make it work.

After some back and forth and I'm getting to this error

```
gst-build-armeabi/gstreamer_android.c:2:21: fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory
```

I know where `gst.h` is but I don't know how to make it visible for the compilation process.

I tried adding the includes path on Android.mk like this `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -IC:\PROGRAM FILES\gstreamer\include` but didn't work.

How can I make files on path `C:\PROGRAM FILES\gstreamer\include` visible to the ndk build?

Comment: How is this a Java question?

Answer (score 0):

Android NDK does not like paths with spaces. Move your gstreamer includes to a different location, or as the last resort try `-Ic:/progra~1/gstreamer/include`